# SQL Server connection middleware?

Tags: sql-server

I have an application that cannot be modified that connects to a SQL Server database using a hardcoded connection string with windows authentication.

I need to move the database to another server but as I cannot modify the hardcoded connection string - I am looking for something to act as a local connection that will then relay the query to the remote database and return the result back to the app.

The only other way I can see to do this is to upgrade from SQL Server Express and use database replication but that will be expensive option for what I need.

Can anyone suggest any software to do this or recommend an alternative method?

Thanks

**Update:**

The connection string also uses Windows authentication which will not work on the remote server.

Comment: Can't you just give the new server the same name? I'm not even going to ask about the hard coded connection string.

Comment: Modify the hard-coded connection. Or change the DNS settings so the name points to the new database. Or use the *same* name for the new server. You can also [create server aliases](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/create-or-delete-a-server-alias-for-use-by-a-client?view=sql-server-ver15) on the client machine(s)

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid - the database server is the same machine where the app runs (ie, 'localhost') so no, unfortunately.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - its a 3rd party app that was written a long time ago. I've tried hacking the exe but to no avail.

Comment: @Gavin where does this app get its connection string from? Is it hard-coded? Does it come from a configuration file? In any case what you ask is more like - "how can I connect to a different machine through localhost"

Comment: Configuring a server alias on the client machine will work, though, with no change to the software. These can be used to literally redirect *anything* -- even connections to the local machine with `.` (although, to prevent confusion, that's not exactly recommendable). All that's needed is an *exact* match on the server name used.

Comment: [This article](https://mariusschulz.com/blog/how-to-configure-a-sql-server-alias-for-a-named-instance-on-a-development-machine) shows how to create an alias named `(local)\SomeInstance` that points to a remote machine

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - literally hardcoded - stored in the binary file.

Comment: Then try creating an alias named exactly the same, eg `localhost\SQLExpress`

Comment: An alias can't help you if you can't authenticate, but what can help there is running the application under different credentials, or if that's not possible using the Credential Manager to give the account it runs under a Windows credential for `machine:1433` to authenticate with. You may have some trouble getting that to work for non-interactive accounts, though. The only thing that's not possible is mapping integrated authentication logins to SQL logins -- that would require a full-featured TDS proxy, and to my knowledge there's no such thing.

Answer (score 1):

If your workstations don't need access to the old server, you could perhaps solve this with DNS, using a `cname` record to point the old server name to the new. If you can't do this organization wide, you might be able to use entries in the **hosts** file on the impacted workstations.

---

I just saw this in the comments:

> the database server is the same machine where the app runs (ie, 'localhost')

In that case, you want to figure out what the connection string is using, and the **hosts** entry should be able to accomplish this.

Comment: If it's literally using `localhost` or the local machine name, adding an entry in `hosts` to redirect that to the remote server will not work (on recent versions of Windows, at least); the network stack ignores such entries for localhost resolution. (That's ignoring the potential problems you could have with other applications if it did work.) If it's using `.` or `(local)`, no DNS redirection will help you.

Answer (score 0):

In old server you can define linked server, pointing it to new one and create queries to link to remote tables; you can use different credentials for it. You may get some performance problems (esp update statements may slow down).

Comment: There's no reason for this. There are many ways to use one name to point to different machines, eg through DNS or server aliases